# make a custom object from the following data

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm trying to make an Object from and array of objects and other objects for a customs final object (example in code) . Iv'e tried to do forEach on the array and create a new object and push it to the final array but had no luck. the numbers in `snapObj` could have the digit that's not the first in the object (digit0 could be digit1...) in `dataArr` this makes it hard for me to find the correct one and represent as needed. any recommendations?

```js
var dataArr = {};

//First array of objects
var arrayContactsWithNames = [{
  "digits0": "5555648583",
  "digits1": "4155553695",
  "name": "Kate Bell",
}, {
 "digits0": "5554787672",
 "digits1": "4085555270",
 "digits2": "4085553514",
 "name": "Daniel Higgins Jr.",
}, {
  "digits0": "8885555512",
  "digits1": "8885551212",
  "name": "John Appleseed",
}, {
  "digits0": "5555228243",
  "name": "Anna Haro",
}, {
  "digits0": "5557664823",
  "digits1": "7075551854",
  "name": "Hank M. Zakroff",
}, {
 "digits0": "5556106679",
 "name": "David Taylor",
}];

// Second object
var snapObj = {
  "5556106679": "test 1",
  "7075551854": "test 2",
  "8885551212": "test 1"
};


/* This is what I want to get:

var dataArr = [{
  "test 1": {
    "5556106679": "David Taylor",
    "8885551212": "John Appleseed"
  }
}, {
  "test 2": Object {
    "7075551854": "Hank M. Zakroff",
  }
}]
*/


// This is what I tried
arrayContactsWithNames.forEach((i) => {
  if (i in snapObject) {
     const newObj = Object.assign({snapObject[i],{ name },{digits${i}}});
     dataArr.push(newObj);
  }
});
```

Comment: Recommendation #1: Remove `async`. You're working with synchronous code.

Comment: edited thanks was left from previous attempts

Comment: Where do `arrayContactsWithNames` and `snapObj` come from? Do you have any chance of changing them or do you _have to_ work with them like they are?

Comment: `snapObj` cant be changed but `arrayContactsWithNames`comes from mapping a contact array of object and reduced to just the name and numbers

Comment: @J.lan I have posted the solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai it does thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is to first create a Object dictionary of the form `number:name` and use it for lookup from the second object. This is most optimal since it only takes O(1) to lookup a key in an object.

```js
var arrayContactsWithNames = [{
  "digits0": "5555648583",
  "digits1": "4155553695",
  "name": "Kate Bell",
}, {
 "digits0": "5554787672",
 "digits1": "4085555270",
 "digits2": "4085553514",
 "name": "Daniel Higgins Jr.",
}, {
  "digits0": "8885555512",
  "digits1": "8885551212",
  "name": "John Appleseed",
}, {
  "digits0": "5555228243",
  "name": "Anna Haro",
}, {
  "digits0": "5557664823",
  "digits1": "7075551854",
  "name": "Hank M. Zakroff",
}, {
 "digits0": "5556106679",
 "name": "David Taylor",
}];

var snapObj = {
  "5556106679": "test 1",
  "7075551854": "test 2",
  "8885551212": "test 1"
};

let parsedArr = arrayContactsWithNames.reduce((acc,{name,...digits}) => {
  Object.values(digits).forEach(digit => { acc[digit] = name });
  return acc;
}, {});  // create a { number : name } mapping with some es6 magic. Refer Object destructuring and spread operator to know how the digit0,digit1 etc are extracted. 
// console.log(parsedArr) 

let parsedObj = Object.keys(snapObj).reduce((acc,num) => { 
  let val = snapObj[num]
  if(!acc[val])
    acc[val] = {}
  acc[val][num] = parsedArr[num]; // use the lookup object with the number
  return acc;
},{}); // A simple reducer to create a new object in the desired shape.

console.log(parsedObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, consider this sample:

```js
const data = {}

const snap = {
 '5556106679': 'test 1',
 '7075551854': 'test 2',
 '8885551212': 'test 1'
}

const objects = [
{
 'digits0': '5555648583',
 'digits1': '4155553695',
 'name': 'Kate Bell',
},
{
 'digits0': '5554787672',
 'digits1': '4085555270',
 'digits2': '4085553514',
 'name': 'Daniel Higgins Jr.',
},
{
 'digits0': '8885555512',
 'digits1': '8885551212',
 'name': 'John Appleseed',
},
{
 'digits0': '5555228243',
 'name': 'Anna Haro',
},
{
 'digits0': '5557664823',
 'digits1': '7075551854',
 'name': 'Hank M. Zakroff',
},
{
 'digits0': '5556106679',
 'name': 'David Taylor',
}]

for (const key in snap)
{
 if (!data[snap[key]])
 {
  data[snap[key]] = {}
 }
 
 for (const object of objects)
 {
  for (const i in object)
  {
   if (object[i] === key)
   {
    data[snap[key]][key] = object.name
    break
   }
  }
 }
}

document.querySelector('textarea').value = JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ')
```

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
```